# How to animate 2 images when showing one hide other one in css animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image link which ı want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JakHV.png)

[web page link which i look for](https://business.exetel.com.au/)

I want to create an animation area in my web page . I have a reference web page above and i want to make same animation area . when one images slide down other one is hidden and wait its turn . i used css keyframes for this but i could not get exactly what i want .

```
  <div class="col-log">
             <img src="/img/tuvnord.png" class="resms1" alt="dd"> 
             <img src="/img/ce.png" class="resms2" alt="">
  </div>
```

i have col-log divs like this which fills my card area like showed above image link.

```
.gelisme2 .resms1 {
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: pic1;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 3s;
}
.gelisme2 .resms2 {
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: pic2;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 3s;

}

@keyframes pic1 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -50); 
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 50);
    }
}

@keyframes pic2 {
      0% {
          opacity: 0;
          transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 50)
      }

      100% {
          opacity: 1;
          transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you can do the whole thing with css / keyframes.  I've got the basics roughed out for you, but you'll need to tweak the timings. Everything you need to do that is on this page:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

In the below snippet, the outer container (`.flex-row`) is set to `display:flex` to show the immediate child containers (`.flex-cell`) side by side. The `flex-cell` containers are then set to `display:block` so that their contents are not side-by-side. Within each flex-cell, the logo divs are in pairs, stacked one above the other *(which makes it easier to do the slideUp / slideDown animations)*.

The snippet uses one `@keyframes` definition for all "top" logo divs, and one `@keyframes` definition for all bottom logo divs. You might find it easier to give each logo div (`dimg`) its own keyframe definition. Whatever  is easiest. Get it working first, then streamline it second - it's too easy to get confuzzled when trying to do both at the same time. Start out with just one logo pair, get that couple working the way you want, then add another `flex-cell`.

Again, the timing isn't quite right with the below example but I'm sure you can manage to tweak it to perfection. *(Note that the first one (timing) is different from the other two. I started playing with the timing, to make the top/bottom changes overlap a bit, but decided that you'll be fine from this point forward. That's why the first pair looks quite different.)*

```css
.flex-row{display:flex;}
.flex-cell{display:block;padding:5px 20px;max-height:45px;border:1px solid #ddd;}
img{width:70px;height:40px;}
.twoA, .twoB, .twoC{opacity: 0;}
.oneA, .oneB, .oneC{opacity: 1;}

.oneA{
  transition: transform .3s;
  animation: doOne  6s linear 0s infinite forwards;
}
.oneB{
  transition: transform .3s;
  animation: doOne  6s linear .5s infinite forwards;
}
.oneC{
  transition: transform .3s;
  animation: doOne  6s linear 1s infinite forwards;
}
.twoA{
  transition: transform .3s;
  animation: doTwo  6s linear 2s infinite forwards;
}
.twoB{
  transition: transform .3s;
  animation: doTwo  6s linear 3.5s infinite forwards;
}
.twoC{
  transition: transform .3s;
  animation: doTwo  6s linear 4s infinite forwards;
}

@keyframes doOne {
   0% {opacity:0; transform: translate(0, -15px);}
   15%{opacity:0;transform: translate(0, -15px);}
   18%{opacity:1;transform: translate(0, 0px);}
   40%{opacity:1;transform: translate(0, 0px);}
   45%{opacity:1;transform: translate(0, 0px);}
   50%{opacity:0;transform: translate(0, 25px);}
  100%{opacity:0;transform: translate(0, 25px);}
}

@keyframes doTwo {
   0% {opacity:0; transform: translate(0, 0px);}
   15%{opacity:0;transform: translate(0, 0px);}
   18%{opacity:1;transform: translate(0, -40px);}
   40%{opacity:1;transform: translate(0, -40px);}
   45%{opacity:1;transform: translate(0, -40px);}
   50%{opacity:0;transform: translate(0, 0px);}
  100%{opacity:0;transform: translate(0, 0px);}
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="flex-cell">
    <div class="dimg oneA"><img src="https://business.exetel.com.au/images/partners/Optus.svg" /></div>
    <div class="dimg twoA"><img src="https://business.exetel.com.au/images/partners/AAPT.svg" /></div>
  </div><!-- .flex-cell -->
  <div class="flex-cell">
    <div class="dimg oneB"><img src="https://business.exetel.com.au/images/partners/Megaport.svg" /></div>
    <div class="dimg twoB"><img src="https://business.exetel.com.au/images/partners/Cisco.svg" /></div>
  </div><!-- .flex-cell -->
  <div class="flex-cell">
    <div class="dimg oneC"><img src="https://business.exetel.com.au/images/partners/Cirrus.svg" /></div>
    <div class="dimg twoC"><img src="https://business.exetel.com.au/images/partners/Opticomm.svg" /></div>
  </div><!-- .flex-cell -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add an "animation-delay" to the correct class you want to keep it waiting if the other animation is done